# Bootstrap carousel "active" indicator is not cycling

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a custom jQuery plugin to convert a Bootstrap grid into a carousel for mobile devices. For example, let's say I want to display a group of div's as a regular grid for viewports over 1000px wide, and then transform those div's into a carousel for viewports under that. This is the interface:

```
$(".row").gridCarousel({
    threshold: "1000px", // Grid / Carousel threshold (viewport max-width)
    indicators: true, // Insert carousel indicators?
    controls: true, // Insert carousel controls?
    carousel: {interval: false}, // Configuration object passed to Bootstrap's carousel
});
```

So far, so good. The issue I'm running into is that the carousel "active" indicator is not being cycled after crossing the viewport-width threshold for a second time.

Steps:

1. Start with a desktop viewport, see the content as a grid.
2. Switch to a narrow viewport, and the content is transformed into a carousel. Indicators work fine.
3. Switch back to a wide viewport. Content is displayed as a grid again.
4. Switch to a narrow viewport again, the content is transformed into a carousel, but the "active" indicator is not moving. You can still click on the indicators and you'll be taken to the correct slide, but the "active" class is not being updated.

I've setup a [demo for the plugin](http://codepen.io/jerivas/pen/pjavWE?editors=001). It contains the complete source of the plugin and then a call to it at the end. You can resize the CodePen viewport to see the effect and reproduce the problem.